# reportMissingImports Python error but import works fine

Tags: python, fastapi

When I install package with python and import it, I often get a missing imports message such as:

**Import "fastapi" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports**

The imports always work perfectly fine, the fastapi example above will run a server and I can build an API without issue.

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and how I could get rid of it?

Comment: You probably have different interpreters on vs-code and your terminal where you are running the script from... Can you check that?

Comment: are you using any IDE?

Comment: `reportMissingImports` is a VS Code error. Pylance cannot find your site-packages and/or the virtual environment you are using.

Answer (score 3):

## The causes could be:

1. The name of the file - `fastapi.py`, if you name it in this could way you would get import errors. (Avoid filenames similar to package names)
2. Installing on other environments. Most of the time it happens when you use both `Conda` and `PiP` on you system.
3. If you run the code from VS Code, check if the `same interpreter` is selected.

#### Verify the installation:

```bash
$ pip list | grep fastapi
```

#### Suggestions:

OPT Virtual Environments to avoid these troubles.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was having the virtual environment i.e. (.env) folder in the same root directory as the Python file.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall fastapi again separately.

pip install <s>'fastapi[all]'</s>

```bash
pip install fastapi
pip install uvicorn
```

Answer (score -1):

reinstall fastapi in the venv you are using

Comment: This is a duplicate of part of the accepted answer. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute. You can show your support for an original answer by upvoting.